# Display the result and the details separately in SSRS 2012

Tags: database, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report in SSRS 2012 which count the number of rows (nb_flow et nb_GPFlow) of 2 DataBase 
with this script

```
SELECT  (SELECT rows 
         FROM  sys.sysindexes
         WHERE      (id = OBJECT_ID('BentekDatabase.dbo.flow')) AND (indid < 2)) 
            AS nb_flow,
         (SELECT COUNT(OriginId) AS Expr1
          FROM  DataWarehouse.dbo.GPFlow
           WHERE  (LoaderCode = 'BTK'))
          AS nb_GPFlow
```

and I added a calculated field (Test_Equal) to compare the 2 numbers of rows, Test_Equal expression =  `=IIF(Fields!nb_GPFlow.Value = 3* Fields!nb_flow.Value, "OK", "NOK" )`

When I run the script it works perfectly, but I want to put the Test_Equal as the first result and when I click to the field in goes to another tab which display the other 2 fields (nb_flow , nb_gpflow)
Any help?

Comment: Sorry, would you please clarify whet you mean by "Test_Equal as the first result". Are you trying to move the calculated field up in the field list dialog of the dataset?

Comment: I mean 2 pages, the fisrt page with the Test_Equal field and when I click on it I m redirected to see the details of nbflow and nb_gpflow

Answer (score 0):

To force a hard page break you should put all elements that you want on page 1 in a Rectangle control, see Toolbox-->Rectangle. Make sure you set the PageBreak.BreakLocation property of the Rectangle to break after it is rendered. You may want to add another Rectangle for page two.